# Cannot install compass

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass

I am running OSX Lion. I am trying to install Compass with:

```
$ sudo gem install compass
```

Then I get an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20140827-6494-1d822e4-0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/extensions/universal-darwin-11/1.8/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

I cannot install Xcode because it won't install on OSX Lion. I was using the old compasss at one time but it didn't work with Suzy 2. I'll be honest, I am not the best at Command line. I just want to get Sass, Compass, and Suzy working together.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mac you can still download xCode 4.6 from the app store and get the command line tools, i'm running Lion as well.